# Add mouse hover event on marker OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, geojson, mousehover

How can I add a mouse hover event on the marker and not on the map. my current code displays a marker using geojson file. I want to display popup on mouse hover on the marker which should show the feature name from geojson file and remove popup when it's not on the marker.how can I achieve this in OpenLayer.

```
    var marker = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
          url: "data/marker.js"  
      }),
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                scale:0.03,
                src: "icons/circle.png"
              })
          })  
    });
```

Comment: Same as example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html except for hover replace `map.on('click'`,with `map.on('pointermove'`

Comment: @ Mike i tried following the above link which you sent but somehow it does not add work .

Comment: 'map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        var name = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
          return feature.get('name');
        })
        if (name) {
          container.style.display="block";
          var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
          content.innerHTML = name;
          overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        } else {
          container.style.display="none";
        }
      });
      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel) ? 'pointer' : '';
      }); '

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-silence-e55z5?file=/main.js